# Remainder rem() and mod() not working properly

Tags: matlab

I am stuck in finding checking whether a variable has value equal to an integer not. The given are the MALAB commands. The variable `cc` has value `1.0000` and I am checking whether its remainder is zero or not. it should be zero but it gives `1`. Why doesn't this give `0`?

```
>> cc
cc =
    1.0000
>> rem(cc,1)
ans =
    1.0000
>> rem(1.0000,1)
ans =
     0
>> mod(1.0000,1)
ans =
     0
>> mod(cc,1)
ans =
    1.0000
>> mod(1.0000,1)
mod(cc,1)
```

Comment: ohhh thank you fprintf() returns 0.99999999999999989000000000000000 and 1==c return 0.

Comment: Now as it is very very near to 1, how can it convert it to 1? not by floor or ceil because I want to convert only those value to their nearest integer which are very very near to it, not all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `fprintf("%.32f\n",cc);`. `cc` is not exactly `1`, as you think it is.

Try also `1==cc` to see what that returns.

You can always round with your own criteria, as:

```
if abs(round(cc)-cc)<1e-8 % or some other number, you choose
    cc=round(cc);
end
```